# What is the difference between ClassName.m() and (new ClassName()).m() m() is a static method

Tags: java, static

What is the difference between `ClassName.m()` and `(new ClassName()).m()` `m()` is a static method.

Comment: For this reason, the constructor of Utility classes is usually private. If you use `enum` for a Utility class, it will be private automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that in your second example you are creating an unnecessary object in memory.

It is still calling the same static method for the `ClassName` class.

It is recommended to use `ClassName.m()` to avoid unnecessary object creation and to provide context to the developers indicating that a static method is indeed being called.

Comment: It might not be the same. The constructor call may actually change the result of the static method - see my answer below for an example.

Comment: @Total You are right, but your example seems more of a programming puzzle than a recommended programming standard.

Comment: oh for sure it's not recommended, and the reason it's not is exactly because it would be so easy to introduce a bug with it, as seen below. However, people have this tendency to do bad things in code all the time, and you have to be aware of what can go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

1. The second has an extra call, which means it might change the outcome. This may be bad, may not, but it is something to consider. See example on how this can work.
2. The second creates an extra object. That's bad.
3. The second implies you're calling a method on an object, not on the class itself, which confuses people who read it. That's also bad. See example for how this can be very bad!

Consider the following, reason 1:

```
class ClassName {
    static int nextId;
    static int m() { return nextId; }
    int id;
    ClassName() { id = nextId; nextId++; }

    /**
     C:\junk>java ClassName
     2
     2
     3
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassName();
        new ClassName();
        System.out.println(ClassName.m());
        System.out.println(ClassName.m());
        System.out.println((new ClassName()).m());
    }
}
```

Consider the following, adding on to reason 2, as alluded to by @emory:

```
class ClassName {

    // perhaps ClassName has some caching mechanism?
    static final List<ClassName> badStructure = new LinkedList<ClassName>();

    ClassName() {
         // Note this also gives outside threads access to this object
         // before it is fully constructed! Generally bad...
         badStructure.add(this); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassName c1 = new ClassName(); // create a ClassName object
        c1 = null; // normally it would get GC'd but a ref exist in badStructure! :-(
    }
}
```

Consider the following, reason 3:

```
class BadSleep implements Runnable {

    int i = 0;
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Thread t = new Thread(new BadSleep());
        t.start();

        // okay t is running - let's pause it for a second
        t.sleep(1000); // oh snap! Doesn't pause t, it pauses main! Ugh!
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Regarding #2 - since we are entering the realm of unconventional programming - if you added some code to the ClassName constructor that added the newly created object to some existing data structure (bad coding practice), then the object would remain reachable.  So the created object would not necessarily be extra to the program.

Comment: @emory It would still require the time to allocate the memory, walk through the constructor which may take time to initialize other variables (which also require time to allocate if they're objects), and take up memory until it was garbage collected. And the garbage collection takes some time too. Now, one could call that a premature optimization (perhaps the memory and time issues are so small no one cares) and if it's already in production I wouldn't take it out unless it's been identified as an issue. But going forward I certainly would.

Comment: If you had ClassName { public static List<ClassName> classNames ; ... ; ClassName(){... classNames.add(this) .... } then the newly created object would be in the static classNames variable and thus reachable.  Some part of the program may depend on the object being in the classNames list.  I am not saying that this is a good practice - just that you can not guarantee that the elimination of the construction of the object will not have undesirable unintended bad effects - without examining the code.

Comment: @Emory that's true, I had misread your comment. Indeed that is simply another reason to avoid the convention of making an object just to use a method that should be static. I'll add that in.

Answer (score 1):

From an external observer's perspective, there's no difference. Both ways result in a call to the method which can only do the exact same thing in either case. You should never do the second one, though, as it just doesn't make sense to create an object in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If `m()` is a static method, it's generally correct practice to use `ClassName.m()` since `m()` is a method of `ClassName`, not an object of `ClassName`.